# Randomly can't connect to guest vm in libvirt

Tags: qemu, kvm, libvirt

I cannot reliably trigger this, although if I spin up many vms at a time and then attempt to connect to some of them, I run into this condition:

```
$ ping 192.168.122.135
PING 192.168.122.135 (192.168.122.135) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.122.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.122.1 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.122.1 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Note that this does not happen for all VMs that I create and start, only a handful of them (randomly).

The vm that has obtained the ip `192.168.122.135` has the following for its network in its domain xml:

```
<interface type='network'>
  <mac address='52:54:00:3d:72:ab'/>
  <source network='default'/>
  <target dev='vnet0'/>
  <model type='virtio'/>
  <alias name='net0'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x0'/>
</interface>
```

And the default network is defined as (and yes, 22 vms are currently running):

```
<network connections='22'>
  <name>default</name>
  <uuid>69674b8b-f067-4513-b594-3e52360f391b</uuid>
  <forward mode='nat'>
    <nat>
      <port start='1024' end='65535'/>
    </nat>
  </forward>
  <bridge name='virbr0' stp='on' delay='0'/>
  <ip address='192.168.122.1' netmask='255.255.255.0'>
    <dhcp>
      <range start='192.168.122.2' end='192.168.122.254'/>
    </dhcp>
  </ip>
</network>
```

The output from ifconfig for `vnet0` (referenced by the VM's network domain xml) and `virbr0` (used by the `default` network as shown above):

```
$ sudo ifconfig vnet0
vnet0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:54:00:3d:72:ab
          inet6 addr: fe80::fc54:ff:fe3d:72ab/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:425 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1304 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500
          RX bytes:57503 (57.5 KB)  TX bytes:67257 (67.2 KB)
```

and

```
$ sudo ifconfig virbr0
virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:54:00:08:e9:a4
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:882508 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2527165 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:93980992 (93.9 MB)  TX bytes:3047773583 (3.0 GB)
```

Below is the partial output from `ip route list`:

```
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.122.1
```

The route output above makes me think that it *should* be working. BUT ITS NOT. and it only fails sometimes, and works most of the time.

Why can't I connect to the guest (`192.168.122.135`) from the host??

I was originally using filters, but removing the filters from the VM's domain xml has no effect on this condition randomly showing up. If I spin up many VMs at the same time I can get it to happen to a lot of them. Some of the VMs work just fine though and allow me to connect.

Also, I am using ubuntu 14.04.3:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

With kernel `3.19.0-30-generic`.

More info - virsh version:

```
$ virsh --version
1.2.2
```

libvirtd version:

```
$ libvirtd --version
libvirtd (libvirt) 1.2.2
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment... But I have a few suggestions on things you could try to further explore the problem.

**Question:** Does assigning an IP address in the 192.168.122.X subnet on vnet0 do anything? The route that is configured seems to suggest that your traffic will go to **virbr0** since it has the **192.168.122.1** IP address. If you can't ping any other devices in that subnet, then I suspect that's the issue.

***If that doesn't get you anywhere...***

- **Packet trace on host / VM**

  Try doing a packet dump on virbr0 and on the internal VM interface when this occurs. Ping the VM, and see what kind of traffic you see.

  `sudo tcpdump -n -i virbr0 -v "icmp or arp"`

  Depending on what you see there, will help narrow down the source of the problem. If you're not even getting your pings on that interface, then it's a routing issue on the host. If pings are going in, but the VM isn't seeing them, then it's a network/routing issue with the libvirt network.

  I recommend also doing the above with a working VM, so you have a reference to compare the traffic against.
- **Check ARP Cache**

  Check your ARP cache on the host when this occurs. Does the mac address exist in the cache? Maybe it's getting mangled...

  To dump the arp cache:

  `# arp`
- **Check your libvirt logs**

  If configured, libvirt will log to syslog using the 'libvirtd' tag. Check your configuration to be sure this is enabled. It seems unlikely it's a libvirt issue, but it wouldn't hurt to turn on the logging.

  To enable this setting

  `# vi /etc/libvirt/libvirtd.conf`

  Add the line

  `log_outputs_"1:syslog:libvirtd"`

  Restart libvirt

  `# service libvirt-bin restart`

Comment: If you can edit this into an answer, please do. Otherwise, you clearly know the rules, so get out there and up your rep!

Comment: Will do! Hard to give an exact answer without more information. Once I have that, i'll revise this and turn it into a real answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue. I just tried following command to check whether machine is installed properly or not.

```
lsmod | grep kvm
```

If it is showing kvm details then machine is installed properly.

After that to restart the services

```
service libvirtd restart
```

Also check gateway using the below command

```
netstat -rn
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same network setting, and similar problem in a CentOS 7 host. Eventually, it turned out that the problem was guest VM's firewall setting blocked echo request and other external connection. After changing the firewall setting, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

My case, I've a hardware server where Libvirt is installed.

On this server I create VM in where install libvirt and after that I've get random network interruption and ping response with `192.168.122.1`:

```
From 192.168.122.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
```

I've fixed this be deleting default libvirt network on hardware server like this:

```
virsh net-destroy default
virsh net-undefine default
```